# About ArrayList in future use?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, save, future

I am a java beginner and learning the oop concept. I already success to store the object value into a arraylist and i try to display the arraylist in the main method. But the problem is if i remove the add value code in the main method and display again the arraylist. The arraylist will show the null value which is []. Please help me and is this is my understanding problem or need to store in txtfile? database or what to get the or store the arraylist and can use for display all the record, update or delete that i add before

This is for my practice project and unuse the database to create a POS system based on oop concept. I had learn php and c# before and i do the same type project and not very confused because of using database. But now i feel confused how to use the java to create it and can has ability to create member, update member profile and etc based on oop concept. Please help me or give the suggestion. Very thank you.

my super class

```
class Person {
private List<Customer> customers;
private String name;
private String gender;
private String email;

public Person(){
}

public Person(List<Customer> customers){
    this.customers = customers;
}

public Person(String name, String gender, String email){
    ***
}

public List<Customer> getCustomers(){
    return customers;
}

public void addCustomer(Customer customer){
    customers.add(customer);
}

//Getter
***
//Setter}
```

my subclass

```
class Customer extends Person{

private int custID;
private static int customerID = 10001;

public Customer(String name, String gender, String email,int custID){

    super(name, gender, email);
    this.custID = custID;
    customerID++;
}

public int getCustID(){
    return custID;
}

public static int getCustomerID(){
    return Customer.customerID;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%d%30s%7s%30s\n", getCustID(), getName(), getGender(),getEmail());
}
```

}

My main method

```
public class POS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Customer p1 = new 
Customer("Halo","M","haloworld@gmail.com",Customer.getCustomerID());
    Customer p2 = new 
Customer("Haloo","F","halobitchworld@gmail.com",Customer.getCustomerID()); 


    List<Customer> cList = new ArrayList<>();

    cList.add(p1);  //if remove
    cList.add(p2); // if remove 

    Person customer = new Person(cList);
    System.out.print(customer.getCustomers());

}
```

}

i expect if write the code in main like

```
 { Person person = new Person();
    System.out.print(person);
 }
```

will display the result that i add before

Comment: have you executed? any errors?

Comment: yes and no error. It will output like  [10001                          Halo      M           haloworld@gmail.com
, 10002                         Haloo      F      halobitchworld@gmail.com
] and my problem is how to store and display again and no effect when i remove the add to array method.

Comment: You still need to use a database, there is no shared state between subsequent runs of a program.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If I understand correctly, what you don't understand is that, if you don't add anything to the list, and display that list, it displays an empty list. Isn't that completely normal? What else do you expect and why? Why should an empty list be displayed as a filled list?

Comment: i think Mr @JBNizet understand that what i don't understand. My expect is i can add into array list and the arraylist will stored . Then whatever i remove the add code it also can show because it aleady stored. So How? thankyou for help

Comment: That won't happen just like that. First, because ArrayList doesn't store anything on disk, but in memory. Second because, even if it did, every time you run your code, you create a `new` ArrayList. new means... new. To achieve what you want you would need to store adn read data from a persistent location (a file on the hard disk, a database, etc.). How to do that is way too broad fr a StackOverflow answer. Decide where and how you want to store your data, and read books or tutorials about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the customers to an ArrayList in your main-function a good way to do it would be to set the `List<Customer>` static in your `Person`-class and adding the customers as they get created.

```java
public class Person {

    private static List<Person> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Person> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String email;

    public Person(String name, String gender, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.email = email;
        customers.add(this);
    }

    /* getters */

}
```

now in your main()-function you only have to create the `Customers` and they automatically get added to the `customers` list and therefore you can then get them by calling the static function `getCustomers()`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer p1 = new Customer("Halo","M","haloworld@gmail.com",Customer.getCustomerID());
    Customer p2 = new Customer("Haloo","F","halobitchworld@gmail.com",Customer.getCustomerID());
    System.out.print(Customer.getCustomers());
}
```

To store them you would have to implement some kind of storage system like MySQL or simply a text file if you don't really have to access them from everywhere. You will find plenty of tutorials here on Stackoverflow in how to do that.

**EDIT**

@andy-turner pointed out that doing `customers.add(this);` inside a constructor really is a pain. So you could just create the `ArrayList<Customer>` in your Main-class and then work like this:

```java
private static ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    customers.add(new Customer("Halo","M","haloworld@gmail.com",Customer.getCustomerID()));
    customers.add(new Customer("Haloo","F","halobitchworld@gmail.com",Customer.getCustomerID()));
    System.out.print(customers);
}
```

Comment: No, don't use `customers.add(this)` in the constructor. If you want to add Persons to a list of customers, do that outside the constructor, say in a class which specifically represents a list of customers. Mutable global state like this is a pain, but inescapably mutating global state is a pain from many perspectives, not least testing.

Comment: yes okey... so maybe he should just create an `ArrayList<Customer> customers` in his main-class?

Comment: What do you mean by `symbol-error`? can you show me your error? Because I could run my version of the program.

Comment: it cannot find the customers

Comment: Well... you have do declare it as `static` as i did: `private static ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

## Variables in memory are ephemeral

An `ArrayList`, like all of the Java Collections Framework, is a structure for holding data *in memory*. When your program ends its execution, all of that memory is freed. Your `ArrayList` is destroyed.

## Storage

If you want to share data between runs, you must store it.

You can open a file in storage and write data values as text. On next run, read that file, parse the text back into objects, and populate a new `ArrayList`.

You can open a file and have your `ArrayList` write itself to storage using [Java Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) technology. Or you can do the serialization yourself with [another serialization format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats).

Or send your data values to a database, which in turn writes them to storage. On next run, retrieve from database.

Or pass your data over the network to some service which accepts the data on your behalf. On next run, ask the service for your data.

All of this is too broad to discuss on Stack Overflow. You need to do your own research and learning.

## Empty array versus NULL

> The arraylist will show the null value which is [].

The string `[]` represents an empty array, an array holding no elements. Such array is not null! Null means no array at all.

Imagine a bookshelf holding books. That’s like an array holding elements. Remove the books. The empty shelf is like an empty array, with no elements. Now take down the bookshelf and burn it. That’s a null array, meaning no array at all.